# Will Pillars of Eternity end after the final battle?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

Can I continue to play Pillars of Eternity after the final battle?

Comment: I asked the same question for Pillar of eternity 2 https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/390499/7346

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not really. You can play the endgame and it normally will autocreate a savegame, something like "pre-endgame autosave" if you enter the endgame. But anyway, you just can load the old autosave again and play the game from this point on. The game won't go on after you finished the endgame.

Comment: And the game will tell you the moment you cannot come back.