# Will Pillars of Eternity 2 end after the final quest?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity-ii

Same question than [here for Pillar of Eternity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/227247/7346) but for Pillar of Eternity 2. Can I continue to play after I end the main quest? Do I need to finish the extension (DLC) quests before or can I finish the main quest first then focus on extension (DLC) after?

Comment: In case the game end with the main quest, does the game give a warning at the point of no return?